# How to retrieve variable from php to android?

Tags: php, android, json

Anyone can help me on How to retrieve variable from php to android?
I've seen a lot of examples. But in my case, I'm doing this in Backgroundworker.
Also, I want to use the variables on my onPostExecute method.

When I toast the result in onPostExecute , I can see that it is showing the right data I need(like an array). Is there a way I can get it on separate? I want to save it on preference to use in the next activities.

Please help me. Thanks for your time in advance.
Below are the codes:

Backgroundworker.java

```
public class updateData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        try {
            URL url;
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String post_data = "";
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
            String result = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(result);
            String id = jsonobj.getString("id");
            String address = jsonobj.getString("address");

            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // where I want to use id and address
    }

}
```

php code

```
 <?php 
require "conn.php";

$uname = $_GET["email"];   

$sql="select * from users where email = '".$uname."'  ";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $id=$row['user_id'];
        $address=$row['address'];
    } 

$result2["id"] = $uname;
$result2["address"] = $address;
echo json_encode($result2);

}

?>
```

Comment: It looks as if your problem has nothing to do with php. What you get and have is a json text. From that json text you want to extract the value of some variables.

Comment: `result += line;` To restore the lines that should be `result += line + "\n";` But string concatenating is slow. Better use a StringBuilder.

Comment: @Dharman I only have little knowledge about android studio. Can you please give me a hint how can I do it sir? Thnkyou very much.

Comment: What's it have to do with Android studio? I made a point about your PHP code.

Comment: I'm sorry sir. So how am I gonna use prepared statement? @Dharman

Comment: Please read tutorials here: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli

Comment: @blackapps please help me how to save it in preference. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to decode a JSON:

```
public void DecodeJson(String JSON){
    try {
        JSONArray arrayJson = StringToJSONarray(JSON); //String to JSON Array
        JSONObject json = arrayJson.getJSONObject(0); /*In case you have more than one JSONs (not your case)*/
        int decoded_id = json.getInt("id")); /*Set the same name as in your PHP file ("id")*/
        String decoded_address = json.getString("address")); /*Set the same name as in your PHP file ("address")*/

    }catch (JSONException e){
        /*TODO Handle exception*/
    }
}

private JSONArray StringToJSONarray(String JSON) throws JSONException {
    return new JSONArray(JSON);
}
```

I hope it helps !

Comment: thanks for your time sir. where am I supposed to put this?

Comment: I see you have a variable named "result" and there is the answer from PHP stored. Just copy the two functions I gave you and wirte "DecodeJson(result)". Set a breakpoint to see the decoded values. If you need the values outside the function, change it so the function returns an arrayList<object/string>.

Your result variable should look like this: "["id":30, "address":"someString"]
If you still have any issues please tell me how your "result" variable exactly looks like so I can help you 

I use "print json_encode($result2);" but it shouldn't make any difference in your code

Comment: Thank you sir. When I Toast the result **@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // where I want to use id and address 
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }** this is what it toast. {"id":"10","address":"someaddress"} my problem is how can split this information to save in preference. Thank you sir.

Comment: or what do you mean **If you need the values outside the function, change it so the function returns an arrayList<object/string>** what will I change?

Comment: how can i use decoded_id and decoded addresss variable in onPostExecute of updateData(which is another method) . Thankyou :)

Comment: Change the method signature from void DecodeJSON to ArrayList<Object> DecodeJson. Now you can 1. Create an arrayList<Object> in the DecodeJson method and add the decoded values (nameList.add(decoded_id), nameList.add(decoded_address). At this point you can call the method decodeJson in the postExecute: ArrayList<Object> myValues = DecodeJson(result)

Comment: `return JSON;` says an error **incompatible types** what should i do?

Comment: Update your question with your new code and the error message please so i can resolve this issue for your :)

Answer (score 0):

in your php codes change **echo** to **return**.

```
<?php 
   require "conn.php";
   $uname = $_GET["email"];   
   $sql="select * from users where email = '".$uname."'  ";
   $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   if($result){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $id=$row['user_id'];
    $address=$row['address'];
   } 
   $result2["id"] = $uname;
   $result2["address"] = $address;
   return json_encode($result2);
  }
?>
```

in java code:

```
public class updateData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    try {
        URL url;
        url = new URL(params[0]);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String post_data = "";
        bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
        String result = "";
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        return result;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(result);
        String id = jsonobj.getString("id");
        String address = jsonobj.getString("address");
}
}
```

call your class in OnCreate methods:

```
new updateData("http://exampleurl.com/api").execute();
```

Comment: @hosien moradi Thank you sir. But it give me an error.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @xxx log result and you see result is empty or no

Comment: Is it not that this code  JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(result);
        String id = jsonobj.getString("id");
        String address = jsonobj.getString("address") should be after the while loop in do in background?

Comment: @xxx 1- comment on the first three lines in the method onPostExecute. 2-log result : log.d(“debuggg”,result); 3-check if the variable is empty?

Comment: No its not empty. Even before I posted the question. My problem is. How can i save the id and address in preference. Thank you sir.

Comment: @xxx you can use hawk library for saving in preference to easily. Parse JSONObject and save with hawk